# how to validate child form from parent component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I have a child component which includes form:

```
<el-form :model="abc" ref="ruleForm" :rules="rules">
      <el-form-item prop="files">
        <abc-card :title="getTranslation('abc.files')">
          <file-selector v-model="abc.files" />
        </abc-card>
      </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

And I want to add simple validations to this form:

```
rules: function () {
      return {
        files: [
          {
            type: 'object',
            required: true,
            trigger: 'change',
            message: 'Field required',
          },
        ],
      };
    },
```

But my click button is in the parent component:

```
<files v-model="editableAbc" ref="editableTab" />
<el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm()">Create</el-button>

methods: {
submitForm() {
        this.$refs.form.validate((isValid) => {
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    ////API CALLS////
  });
      },
    }
```

So I am trying to achieve that when the button is clicked the navigation should be rendered. How can I do that?

Comment: If for some reason you can't have the submitForm button in the child component where the form actually is, you should add a prop to your child component that the parent sets when the button is clicked informing the child of the submit.  Child should then handle the validation of the form.  In return, the child's validation result can be emitted back up to the parent if you want to do something with it there.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I understand the logic but dont know how to imply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, My suggestion would be to use a `ref` on child component to access its methods and then on submit click in parent component, trigger the child component method.

In parent component template **:**

```
<parent-component>                                                                                                                                                        
      <child-component ref="childComponentRef" />
      <button @click="submitFromParent">Submit</button>                                                                      
</parent-component>
```

In parent component script **:**

```
methods: {
  submitFromParent() {
    this.$refs.childComponentRef.submitForm();
  }
}
```

In child component script **:**

```
methods: {
  submitForm() {
    // Perform validations and do make API calls based on validation passed.
    // If you want to pass success or failure in parent then you can do that by using $emit from here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cannot do the api calls in my child component because it becomes too complicated, do you recommend something for this also?

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @themaninthepinksuit In that case after validation, you can emit the event from your child component `submitForm` method with the success and then based on that you can make an Api call in your parent.

Answer (score 0):

The "files" component is the form you're talking about?
If so, then ref should be placed exactly when calling the 'files' component, and not inside it. This will allow you to access the component in your parent element.

```
<files v-model="editableAbc" ref="ruleForm" />
```

There is a method with the props, which was mentioned in the comments above. I really don't like it, but I can tell you about it.
You need to set a value in the data of the parent component. Next you have to pass it as props to the child component. When you click the button, you must change the value of this key (for example +1). In the child component, you need to monitor the change in the props value via watch and call your validation function.

```
// Parent
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      updateCount: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      // yout submit method
      this.updateCount += 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Child

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    updateCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  watch: {
    updateCount: {
      handler() {
        this.validate();
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      // yout validation method
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And one more solution. It is suitable if you cannot place the button in the child component, but you can pass it through the slot.
You need to pass the validate function in the child component through the prop inside the slot. In this case, in the parent component, you will be able to get this function through the v-slot and bind it to your button.

```
// Parent 
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <ChildComponent>
      <template #button="{ validate }">
        <button @click="submitForm(validate)">My button</button>
      </template>
    </ChildComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },

  methods: {
    submitForm(cb) {
      const isValid = cb();
      // your submit code
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Child

<template>
  <div class="child-component">
    <!-- your form -->

    <slot name="button" :validate="validate" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    validate() {
      // yout validation method
      console.log("validate");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: But my problem is to communicate between parent and child

Comment: I saw that you are trying to access the validate function of a child component via $refs. In this case, you need to place ref="ruleForm" directly in the parent component where you are trying to access $refs. Refs act directly where they are declared. You cannot access the $refs of a child component. You also need to make sure that the child component really has a validate method.

Comment: I have added additional information to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But in child component there is only form and I need to pass validation/form(I dont know which one) to the parent component. In parent component, there is a button and I can do validation there. But I am really confused about the logic

Comment: try the method using props/watch that I described